# Does Azure Backup include attached Disks

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-backup-vault

I am new to Azure and setting up the backup of multiple Azure VM's, all on the Location.  2 of the 3 VM's have additional data disks attached to them.

Will the Recovery Services Backup policy also back up the data on these disks or do I need to setup a separate backup policy to manage these?  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Azure Backup for VMs include automatically all disks attached to the VM.

Note, there is some limitations to how quickly it can do the backup if there are multiple disks attached. See e.g. [Plan your VM backup infrastructure in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-introduction) for more infromation.

Answer (score 1):

All attached data disks will be included in any VM which is enrolled into backups. Few limitations to take note of below.

There's also a private preview currently running for data disks which are 1TB+ in size, link below.

For Azure VM backup, each VM can have up to 16 data disks with each data disk being of size 1024GB or less.

[Azure Backup (Private Preview) Support Disks up to 4TB](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Instant-recovery-point-and-25fe398a?redir=0)

[Azure Backup FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-backup-faq)